# GruntJS - beautify plugin: Warning: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use GruntJS for a simple task to beautify some js/css, using the grunt-beautify plugin. This is the most basic task and I can't get beautify to run without errors. The uglify task runs fine, I just don't see the problem with the beautify task.

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Task configuration.
    beautify: {
      files: {
         src: '../myProject/css*/*.css',
         dest: './'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      files: {
         src: 'dev/*.css'
      }
    },
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-beautify');

  // Default task.
  //grunt.registerTask('default', ['beautify']);

};


Registering "grunt-beautify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt-beautify/package.json...OK
Parsing /path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt-beautify/package.json...OK
Loading "beautify.js" tasks...OK
+ beautify
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
>> No tasks were registered or unregistered.

Running tasks: beautify

Running "beautify" task
[D] Task source: /path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt-beautify/tasks/beautify.js

Running "beautify:files" (beautify) task
[D] Task source: /path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt-beautify/tasks/beautify.js
Verifying property beautify.files exists in config...OK
Files: ../myProject/css_3.3.6/bootstrap.min.css, ../myProject/css_3.3.6/fonts.css, ../myProject/css_3.3.6/styles.css -> ./
Using beautifier default options.
Warning: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined Use --force to continue.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt-beautify/tasks/beautify.js:52:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:264:15)
    at Object.thisTask.fn (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:82:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:296:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:246:24)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:295:12)
    at /path/to/grunt/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:222:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't help but notice

```
beautify: {
  files: {
     src: '../myProject/css*/*.css',
     dest: './'
  }
}
```

but [grunt-beautify](https://github.com/pix/grunt-beautify#grunt-beautify) is suppose to be run on .js files not .css files. Nothing in the project's [grunt file](https://github.com/pix/grunt-beautify/blob/master/grunt.js) suggests otherwise either.